# Binding to singleton property

Tags: android, mvvmcross

Is there a way to bind property of the VM to any kind of singleton property ( static resource property, property in the singleton service... ) in a way that we don't need to use IMessenger or to handle SingletonServiceResolved OnPropertyChanged?

It feels kind of dirty for me (even if it is in the base class) to have each activity to handle changes in my singleton Clock Property.

```
public class ClockService : ObservableObject, IClockService {
    private DateTime _clock;
    public DateTime Clock { 
        get{ return _clock;} 
        set { _clock = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Clock"); } 
    }
}

public class SomeViewModel : BaseViewModel {
    private IClockService _clockService;
    private IMvxMessenger _messenger;

    public SomeViewModel(IClockService clockService, IMvxMessenger messenger) {
         _clockService=clockService;
         _messenger = messenger;

         //trying to avoid
         clockService.PropertyChanged += OnClockServicePropertyChanged;

    }

    public DateTime MyClock {
       get{return _clockService.Clock;}
    }

    private OnClockServicePropertyChanged(...) {
         if(e.PropertyName=="Clock") RaisePropertyChanged("Clock");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to bind to a singleton is to expose the singleton via a property on your ViewModel:

```
 public Thing MySingleton
 {
    get
    {
       return Thing.Instance;
    }
 }
```

---

Update after comment that the singleton isn't constant:

You could use another constant singleton as a holder - and this can then implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` - e.g.:

```
public class ThingHolder : MvxNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static readonly ThingHolder Instance = new ThingHolder();

    private Thing _thing;
    public Thing CurrentThing
    { 
      get { return _thing; } 
      set { _thing = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => CurrentThing); } 
    }
}
```

Your VMs can then properties like:

```
 public ThingHolder ThingHolder
 {
    get
    {
       return ThingHolder.Instance;
    }
 }
```

Your views can then bind to expressions like `ThingHolder.CurrentThing`

Comment: Problem with this solution is that UI will never get PropertyChanged ... so it wouldn't refresh. I am asking is there some way under the hood that will help me avoid handling EventSubscription (or messageSubscription)

Comment: Edited after your comment - but really I'd be careful about your use of the `Singleton` term here as I think it may confuse others - `Singleton` is fairly widely understood to mean "only one instance is ever created" - e.g. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern - it's not normally understood to indicate that there's a "current" instance (in my experience).

Comment: I didn't pointed out but IClockService (in this example) is during initialization resolved like singleton by CreatableTypes().EndingWith("Service").AsInterfaces().RegisterAsSingleton(); so there's only one instance of ClockService and it's Clock property. Am I missing something?